# SIG_IGN does not work with PTRACE_TRACEME?

Tags: linux, signals, ptrace

I'm testing an antidebug solution with `ptrace` method

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;
    long (*go)(enum __ptrace_request request, pid_t pid);

    // get a handle to the library that contains 'ptrace'
    handle = dlopen ("libc.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    // reference to the dynamically-resolved function 'ptrace'
    go = dlsym(handle, "ptrace");

    if (go(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0) < 0) {
        puts("being traced");
        exit(1);
    }

    puts("not being traced");

    // cleanup
    dlclose(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute it, I'm always getting a stopped error,

```
# ./a.out
not being traced

[4]+  Stopped                 ./a.out
```

Then I tried to add the SIGSTOP handler like this

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    signal(SIGSTOP, SIG_IGN);
```

And it's still getting a stopped error, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

- `handle = dlopen ("libc.so", RTLD_LAZY)` assigns NULL to `handle`. Dlopen fails because on your GNU/Linux distro (and most other modern distros) `lib.so` isn't a shared library - it's a GNU ld script.

  `dlopen ("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY)` would have succeeded.
- `go = dlsym(handle, "ptrace")` succeeds(!). With glibc, it's OK to pass a NULL pointer as the handle argument to dlsym because glibc happens to use `((void *) 0)` as `RTLD_DEFAULT`.

  This generally won't work on other systems. FreeBSD's dlsym uses `((void *) -2)` as `RTLD_DEFAULT`, and if you call dlsym with a NULL handle, it will look for the symbol within the executable or shared library that called dlsym.
- `go(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0)` succeeds.
- `dlclose(handle)` can't tolerate a NULL handle, and it causes a segfault, so the `SIGSEGV` signal is raised.
- since the process is being traced, receiving a signal results in it being stopped (suspended). Typing `jobs` to your shell will show the signal that made the process stop.

---

The code

```
signal(SIGSTOP, SIG_IGN);
```

won't really do anything. `SIGSTOP` is one of the signals that cannot be caught, ignored, or held.